Error with pagedown in Rmarkdown when running from a Macbook
I have the following YAML for a pagedown template that I usually render in Rmarkdown
---
title: <br> **Report Title** 
author:
  - name: Department   
affiliation:
    address: <br> **Updated - `r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %Y')`**
title_textsize: "85pt"
author_textsize: "60pt"
column_numbers: 3
logoright_name: Logo.png
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
    - \captionsetup{font=Huge}
output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html:
    self_contained: false
columnline_width: "3mm"
columnline_style: dashed
primary_colour: "#6d1d26"
secondary_colour: "#6d1d26"
accent_colour: "#6d1d26"
title_textcol: "#c7af76"
author_textcol: "#c7af76"
affiliation_textcol: "#c7af76"
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---


I've never had any issues with running this from Windows, but I recently switched to a Macbook and I tried to run the same template and I'm getting the following error
Error in pagedown::chrome_print() :
  The browser is not executable: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome


Is there any reason why this error pops up strictly when I run this template on a Macbook? I have verified that I do have Google Chrome installed on my Mac
